# Why can't I open the easter eggs like Tetris on Emacs?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, emacs, terminal.app

I am in terminal on a Mac, and I type in `emacs tetris`. It comes up with a blank page and something at the bottom saying: `Loading image...done`, but that is it. I leave it for a little while but nothing happens. I try `emacs dunnet` and `emacs doctor`, but the same thing happens again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `emacs <something>`, the parameter passed will be a file.

```
echo "test" > test
emacs test
```

This will open the file called "test".

If you want to play Tetris on emacs, just open it with `emacs`, then press `Escape`, then `x`, and then enter `tetris`.

[image]

<sub>I obviously suck at Tetris.</sub>

Comment: Also, if you've executed the (wrong) command before, look in your directory for files called `#tetris#`, and remove them with `rm '#tetris#'`, if necessary.

Comment: Accepted answer. Thank you. Although it is strange because I'm sure `emacs tetris` used to work.

Comment: Hm, I don't know why it should. Default behavior for `emacs` is to take the arguments after the options as the filename, as in `emacs [ command-line switches ] [ files ... ]`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start tetris from the command line, use

```
emacs -f tetris
```

From the manual:

```
-f function, --funcall function
        Execute the lisp function function.
```